# Jquery Ajax Request in old tab blocking new tab from loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am loading data from external interfaces via `$.ajax()` and some of these requests are running up to 20 seconds. The relevant data is then shown after ~1 second.

If the user clicks on a link that opens in a new tab on the same domain, the new tab won't start loading until all XHR Requests in the old tab have finished.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve that problem?

Comment: can you share some of your code?

Comment: Each tab runs in its own process. This is more likely a server-side problem where the task is so intensive that it is blocking the server from responding to any further requests. I would check your server logs and it's performance metrics and consider upgrading it. It's also possible the server has a connection limit per IP. In any case, it sounds like a server-side configuration issue, not a client-side JS one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - thank you for the hint. You were absolutely right. It seems to be a problem with the external connection that is started by the ajax request. If i just put sleep(30) instead of the curl request the new tab loads without any problems.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rory McCrossan - your answer pointed me into the correct direction.

The problem were sessions that have been started by the scripts that i called via Ajax. They blocked the session file and so the other tab didn't have access to it and couldn't load.

I hope this helps someone.